# How to get default Typeface of Android device?

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I have an *Api* class in my application. Inside the *Api* class there is a custom font that has been setup as static. For example:

```java
public static Typeface fontShort;

public Api(Context c, Display d) {
    // I want to change this if user wants to keep using system font style or my custom style
    if (shouldKeepCurrent == true) {
        // Use system default font
        fontTitle =  // ???
    } else {
        // Use my costume font
        fontTitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/custom.ttf");
    }       
}
```

I want to get default and current Typeface of device if user doesn't want to use my custom font!

In Activity class:

```java
TextView myView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
// Change to custom font style or keep current font style
myView.setTypeface(Api.fontTitle);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can get the default Typeface using:

```
if (keep_curren) {
    font_title = Typeface.DEFAULT;
}
```

You can also get the default Typeface based on specified style: `Typeface.defaultFromStyle(int style)`.

More on this: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html).