# How to get my current system font name?

Tags: android

I'm using "cool jazz" font on my android device and i want to get this name on my application there is a option to get the font name?

Comment: do you mean you want to customize the font of your action bar title "the name of your app"

Comment: no, I'm just want to get the name of the font. e.g `chocolate` or `cool jazz`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the name of the font.

The [TypeFace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) class has no method to tell the its name(even it doesn' t override `toString()` to provide more info).

When you use your own font, you just provide the font file or font-family name, the `TypeFace` itself has no idea what' s name of it. Maybe the caller like you knows.

Answer (score -1):

See this
[How to get default Typeface of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293915/how-to-get-default-typeface-of-android-device)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

Comment: It's not returned the typeface name