# How do I find the default fonts on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to understand what are the system default fonts on Android system which is using and get their paths ( directory location )? I know they are in system/fonts , but I do not how to know and find out which of them are using and in which part which system fonts are being applied by system as default. 
I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get default Typeface of Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293915/how-to-get-default-typeface-of-android-device)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get the name/location of the system default font.
You can only get default Typeface, use: `Typeface.DEFAULT`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

Comment: thanks , but this apps in google play store how find out them and changed them , for Example "Fontster.apk" , it can change the system default of any android OS (RR , MIUI , CM ,....) and change it to your desire font
@Huy N